# Длина и содержимое почтового адреса xxx@xxx.xxx

Tags: email

Какие соглашения приняты для максимальной и минимальной длины почтового адреса, и содержимого этой длины?

> xxx@xxx.доменная зона

С доменной зоной всё понятно, 2-3 латинские буквы.

А вот если смотреть [документацию](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1), то получается что длина всего этого удовольствия может быть 255 символов (вместе с собакой), и имя (ххх@) - это 64 символа, включая например "/" - такого я ни разу не видел.

Вот и получается, что почтовый адрес это 64 символа: латинские буквы, несколько странных символов, потом '@', потом 188 символов (включая точку и доменную зону).

Соответственно, встает вопрос о том насколько нормальна сама документация, и что используется в реальной жизни.

Comment: а что вас не устраивает ? в реальной жизни следуют RFC

там вот такая оговорка:

Objects larger than these sizes SHOULD be avoided when
   possible.  However, some Internet mail constructs such as encoded
   X.400 addresses (RFC 2156 [35]) will often require larger objects.
   Clients MAY attempt to transmit these, but MUST be prepared for a
   server to reject them if they cannot be handled by it. ** To the
   maximum extent possible, implementation techniques that impose no
   limits on the length of these objects should be used.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Именно почтовые сервера, особенно поддерживаемые/популярные, как раз совместимы с РФЦ. Больше - пихать смысла нет, возможно, кто-то в индивидуальном порядке и имеет более широкие лимиты, но вероятность быть посланным в 5ХХ - большая.

Вопрос в том, что е-майлы часто много где используются, а там уже фильтрует кто как хочет.

В общем рекомендуется использовать то же метод, которым гугл валидует логины:
 - латинские буквы (строчные и заглавные);
 - цифры;
 - точка ".";
 - возможно "-" и "_", но для полной-полной гарантии лучше не использовать.

Логин (до @) не более 32 знаков. Домен не более 31 знака. В сумме - вложиться в 64 символа. Лучше в 50.

Очень часто народ проверяет е-майлы следующим кодом:

```
 preg_match("%^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z])+$%", $email)
```

и более мягкая форма:

```
preg_match( '/^[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&\'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)+[A-Za-z]$/', $email)
```

Это в основном ищется в нете по запросам "проверка корректности е-майла", и очень похоже, что весьма используется.